# I want to install mysql 8 instead of mariadb

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Good evening,
I did install mariadb 10.4 in order to install magento 2.4.2 but when I did a general update it upgrade to mariadb 10.5 automatically, which is not supported for magento...
As I can't succeed in finding the mariadb-main depo and retrograde I would like to install mysql 8.
So I have removed the mariadb.repo files in etc/yum.repos.d but when I tape in putty:
yum install mysql-server
I have some conflict errors with MariaDB-common-10.5.10-1.e18.x86_64 file in the transaction test...
How can I remove the package/repo and all files of mariadb in order I can install mysql without conflicts?
[screenshot putty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KiSz8.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mysql-commons package conflicts with mariadb one, you can check which mariadb packages are still not removed with `yum list installed | grep MariaDB` and remove the.
Also yum has a plugin for removing trailing dependencies so you can try with that instead `yum install yum-plugin-remove-with-leaves` and when you remove mariadb with yum just add the `--remove-leaves` flag

Comment: Good evening, theses commands seems to not working...

Comment: strange, but anyway you don't need it now as you have a list of a mariadb packages that remained on the system (mariadb-backup, commons and shared) from `yum list installed`
just remove those the same way you removed mariadb-server

Comment: ok, I have do a "yum list installed" then a "yum remove " *Maria* " (symbol * before and after Maria) and it works ! I can install mysql without conflict with MariaDB... thanks you :-)

Comment: No problem, you can accept the answer https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work